# JQuery - Fancytree Could not apply extension drag n drop

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I'm using JQuery fancytree, and I got an error when I use drag'n drop. My project is using other extensions (like Filter, Child Counter) but dnd cannot be apply. I think that I got latest version of fancytree dnd js file (got it on github).

I register the fancytree files like that :

```
<script src="Scripts/fancytree/src/jquery.fancytree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fancytree/src/jquery.fancytree.filter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/fancytree/src/jquery.fancytree.dnd.js"></script>

<script src="Scripts/Treeview_navbar_dnd.js"></script><!--file where the fancytree code is-->
```

And i register the extension like that :

```
$("#treeView").fancytree({
        extensions: ["filter","dnd"],
```

And I have this error :

```
Uncaught Error: Could not apply extension 'dnd' (it is not registered, did you forget to include it?)
```

Could you help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [built version of fancytree from github](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/releases) and include `dist/jquery.fancytree-all.min.js` - from **dist** folder, not *src*.

Note that this is minimized so weights less, also you save 2 request for filter and dnd.